# Wait Until Event Occurs

Tags: c++, sockets, mfc, asynchronous

I'm doing sockets programming. Pretty much new to it.

The application is a Windows Service, in its `ServiceMain()` function I call `CAsyncSocket::Listen()` method, to listen for client connections. But after it starts listening for connections, it'll return and the `ServiceMain()` function will return and the service is stopped.

What I want to do with this is that, wait until a specific event occurs say `WM_QUIT`, till than listen for connections. How to do it?

```
// static member function (callback)
void CNTService::ServiceMain(DWORD dwArgc, LPTSTR* lpszArgv)
{
    // m_Server containts two sockets
    // one for listening and one for accepting connections

    m_Server.StartListening();  // calls Listen method on the listener socket

    // it will return and service will quit
    // which I don't want
}
```

I'm okay with mixing Win32 and MFC, so if it can be done in Win32 please do tell me too :)

Answer (score -1):

In a service you normally would use WaitForMultipleObjects and wait for whatever things your service does (WSAEventSelect for sockets when not using a framework) + a quit event that you signal when the service manager tells you to quit

Comment: Can you tell me how exactly to wait for the client to connect to the server?

Will this work?

m_Listener.Listen();

WaitForSingleObject(m_Listener);

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to handle a socket server is something like (pseudo code with winsock) :

```
bind(listenerSocket);

while(!stopped)
{
     listen(listenerSocket);
     clientSocket = accept(listenerSocket);

     process(clientSocket);
}
```

The listen call is blocking, waiting for connection. This way you can handle multiple connections. the process method usually spawn a thread in a threadpool.

I'm not familliar with MFC sockets but you have the equivalent things in a more OO way. There is many tutorials about this sort of things. You can also use a library handling sockets (you gain portability ...) like [boost](http://www.boost.org).

If you only need to handle a connection and do some process, you only do :

```
bind(listenerSocket);

listen(listenerSocket);
clientSocket = accept(listenerSocket);

process(clientSocket);
```

Comment: You said that you have no problem with win32. I heard no problem wit winsock ... by the way I give you pseudo code. You can find equivalent calls in MFC socket which are for what i recall OO wrapping around winsock.

Comment: Yea, but if I have to follow your way, I'll have to rewrite everything

Comment: I don't know your code but, the idea was to give you the differents steps. I think you have equivalent methods in your MFC sockets. That's why I give you pseudo code and not winsock code. The main point is that after listening you have to accept a connection. then you will get a socket handle that will allow you to receive/send message. anyway, good luck ...